# How do I get a definition's name as a symbol?

Tags: scheme, racket

How do I get a definition's name as a symbol in Scheme and/or Racket? Suppose I have these definitions:

```
(define bananas 123)

(define multiply *)

(define (pythagoras a b)
  (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b))))
```

How can I define `def->symbol` where:

- `(def->symbol bananas)` returns `'bananas`
- `(def->symbol multiply)` returns `'multiply`
- `(def->symbol pythagoras)` returns `'pythagoras`

Is this a case where I have no choice but to learn and use these advanced things called "macros"?

Comment: Aka `quote` eg `(quote bananas) ; ==> bananas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you suspect, we need to use a [macro](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html) - and a very simple one! A normal procedure wouldn't work because the parameters get evaluated *before* calling the procedure, but with a macro we can manipulate the parameters before they get evaluated, and in this case quoting the parameter is all we need to do. In Racket, this is how we'd write it:

```
(define-syntax-rule (def->symbol def)
  'def)
```

Which is shorthand for Scheme's standard macro syntax:

```
(define-syntax def->symbol
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ def) 'def)))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(def->symbol bananas)    ; 'bananas
(def->symbol multiply)   ; 'multiply
(def->symbol pythagoras) ; 'pythagoras
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to quote `def` inside `define-syntax-rule`?

Comment: Give it a try, remove the quote and see what happens: the parameter will get evaluated if we don't quote it, and for the sample input the macro will return 123, *, or a procedure - in fact, we'd be implementing the identity function.

Comment: I guess my question is more like: why doesn't `def->symbol` return `'def`? If the macro is `(define-syntax-rule (def->symbol def) 'lala)`, I get `'lala`, but if it is `(define-syntax-rule (def->symbol def) 'def)`, I don't get `'def`?!

Comment: Because the `def` in the body is matched to the macro's `def` pattern variable, whereas `lala` doesn't match to anything and is interpreted as a regular symbol. Perhaps the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pattern-macros.html) will make it clearer.

Comment: In reality `def->symbol` is just quote with a different name. Instead of `(def->symbol bananas)` you could write `'bananas`